# setTranslate() doesn't work in nested panes in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, translation, transition

I am working on a GUI, where I need to move objects in exact part of GUI. Main windows is split into few parts and I want to be able to move objects in one of these parts.
I tried to write simple code, where I just move simple rectangle in **root** `Group`, to understand how transition translation works. Everything went well. When I wanted to do the exact same thing in my GUI (in one of nested `Group`), it didn't work.
It shows, that new translations were set to object, but object didn't move at all.
I did the exact same thing, except `Groupt` isn't root.

**Code:**

```
/* imports, main() */ 

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Button tmpButton = new Button("Just fill the space");

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
    rect.setOnMousePressed(mousePressedEvent);
    rect.setOnMouseDragged(mouseDraggedEvent);

    Group movablePlace = new Group(); 
    movablePlace.getChildren().add(rect); 

    VBox root = new Root();
    root.geChildren().addAll(tmpButton, movablePlace);


    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
}

EventHandler<MouseEvent> mousePressedEvent = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {    
    /* getting coordinates works fine */
};

EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseDraggedEvent = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {         
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        /* actualize new coordinates and offset - works fine */

        ((Rectangle)event.getSource).setTranslateX(newTranslationX);
        ((Rectangle)event.getSource).setTranslateY(newTranslationY);   
        /* translations of rectangle are set correctly, but it doesn't move */
    }
};
```

Can someone clear up to me, what I did wrong or misunderstood?
Thank you!

Comment: Probably because the rectangles's parent layout (`VBox`). You may consider either to change the layout, or use `Node#setManaged(false)`(`rect.setManaged(false)` in your case).

Comment: This is simply because of the way [`Group`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) works. *"If transforms and effects are set directly on children of this Group, those will be included in this Group's layout bounds"*. So when the layout of the `Group` is computed, it takes into account the translation on the rectangle, and is laid out in the `VBox` according to the `VBox` layout rules. Consequently, you don't "see" the translation. Just use a `Pane` instead of a `Group`.

Comment: Thank you, that is why it worked, when I added another rectangle? Then i saw the movement, because it was based on other components of the group? Do I understand this correctly ? Btw, thank you for that Pane, it helped!